# Cordova 3.0 just using device plugin error?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using Cordova 3.0.  I'm able to create a skeleton project and run it without any problem.  Now I want to add the Device plugin. Here are my steps:
1. Added assets\www\device.js
2. Modified res\xml\config.xml and added:

```xml
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />
</feature>
```

1. Modified AndroidManifest.xml and added:

```xml
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

1. Added src\Device.java
2. In index.html I added script src:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="device.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

In the index.js I added the following code:

```js
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    console.log('device.model=>' + device.model);
},
```

I build and run on the android emulator and get the error:

> 10-03 12:22:49.998: E/Web Console(637): Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/device.js:22
>
> 10-03 12:22:50.489: I/Web Console(637): device.model=>undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:40

Any ideas on what im missing?  I've followed the instructions at the phonegap site
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the official method to install the plugin. Run

`cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git`

from your command line and it should take care of all the modifications for you. You should remove all of your modifications first.

Comment: yeah you really need to use the cordova plugin add command for it to work.  The only difference is i use on windows the following command: cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device to make it work.  I could not get the git to work properly.  It writes the plugin into the cordova_plugins.js which is what gets referenced

Comment: I used above method and i get org.apache.cordova.device already installed on android

Comment: BUt i still get same error message 09-30 13:16:44.433: I/chromium(11468): [INFO:CONSOLE(1235)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (1235)

Comment: I had overriden my cordova.js and so had to do a `plugin remove` and then `plugin add` and I was good to go.